# geodesic map for a single source and multiple destination gmap4 rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to gmaps4 and i have tried a lot but i was not able to find how to create a geodesic map, if i have single source and multiple destination using gmap4 rails.

So far i have tried this

Js

```
  var locations = [
      //Starting Point is "Home", and links to other locations"//
      ['Home', 37.774930, -122.419416],
      ['Location-1', 35.689487, 139.691706],
      ['Location-2', 48.856614, 2.352222],
      ['Location-3', -33.867487, 151.206990]
    ]

    function initMap() {
      var myLatLng = {
        lat: 12.363,
        lng: -131.044
      };
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 3,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        center: {
          lat: 0,
          lng: 0
        }
      });
      var markers = [];
      var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
      // Add the markers and infowindows to the map
      for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
          title: locations[i][0],
          map: map
        })
        markers.push(marker);
        bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());
        if (i > 0) {
          var sitepath = new google.maps.Polyline({
            path: [markers[0].getPosition(), marker.getPosition()],
            geodesic: true,
            strokeColor: '#FF0000',
            strokeOpacity: 1.0,
            strokeWeight: 2,
            map: map
          });
        }
      }
      map.fitBounds(bounds);
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initMap);
```

Html

```
   <div id="map"></div>
```

but i am not able to understand how to do it using gmaps4 rails